# What drawing style are the esurance characters?

Tags: drawing, style-identification

What drawing style are the esurance characters? Actually, more specifically what drawing style is this Gorilla?

[image: Gorilla image]

Comment: It's a vector drawing :]

Comment: What are "the esurance characters"? Looks like the gorilla is from another brand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a vector drawing .

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics):

> Vector graphics is the use of geometrical primitives such as points, lines, curves, and shapes or polygon(s), which are all based on mathematical equations, to represent images in computer graphics.

This character could be created with the help of Illustrator or Inkscape.

See this link for more information on character formatting...

- [Step by step cartoon-character-illustration-tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/16/40-cartoon-character-illustration-tutorials/)
- [How to create a character](http://www.blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-your-own-cartoon-character)

Comment: Vectors are a way of defining lines in software, and while it's become a trendy term to describe a style, it's not really that descriptive, as raster images can look the same, and vector based images can look entirely different. I think a more traditional description would be something like "a line drawing using a posterized coloring"

Comment: @DA01: It's not really [posterized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization), though. Rather, that particular art style is indeed characterized to a large extent by its heavy use of some common features of current-day vector graphics formats and editors, such as Bézier spline outlines with linear (and circular) gradient shading. I don't know if that style has a specific name, but if you called it a "vector cartoon drawing", the chances are people might think of something similar to that image.

Comment: Well, it's not a big deal, of course. More of a pet peeve. IT's not like we call other art 'raster illustration'. And that style has been around for a long while. But I agree, these days, odds are that it would be created with a vector illustration tool.