# How they do to create like these characters

Tags: website-design

I am asking if someone know any tutorial or tools that help me design characters like this in the following image (see the men in the header?):

[image: example character]

and thank you so much.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6060/drawing-people-where-should-i-start/6082#6082 --- http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/what-drawing-style-are-the-esurance-characters/4067#4067 --- http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/illustrator-for-beginners

Comment: draw shapes to look like a face and then fill said shapes with gradients.

Comment: Thanks for your help, what I wanted really is a tool that may have some presets of body elements and I can create my own face character, I don't do well with PS or AI drawing :(

Comment: There's no substitute for artistic talent. There's no magic button to make you an artist/illustrator. If there were, many professionals would be out of work.

Comment: @AbdelouahedErrouaguy there are vector packs available like this one: http://graphicriver.net/item/characters-design-vector-pack/2095292 --- just go to your favorite search engine and look for it.

Comment: If you reword the question to say you're looking for presets and what you tried to search for we can probably reopen the question since I don't think its been asked.

Answer (score 0):

[Vector Tuts](http://vector.tutsplus.com) has articles on [how to draw cartoon faces](http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/cartoon-fundamentals-how-to-draw-a-cartoon-face-correctly/?search_index=9) and they have [articles on how to draw more realistic human figures](http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/human-anatomy-fundamentals-advanced-body-proportions/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20vectortuts%20%28Vectortuts%2b%29). Amazon has books on how to draw cartoon characters or Manga art.

Comment: Thanks for you help, what I wanted really is a tool that may have some presets of body elements and I can create my own face character, I don't do well with PS or AI drawing :(